# Closing lid on my laptop changes the screen resolution when I open it

Tags: windows-xp, lid

I have a Lenovo T60 running XP fully service packed. Every time I close the lid lately it changes the resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered this before:

Use regedit.exe and search for all “LidBehavior” entries. Change the value from 11 to 10 Reboot.

Comment: Amazing...thank you. I have been beating my head against the wall with this problem.

Comment: @user86479 Glad I could help. If you would, please click the check box and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem occur with buggy drivers, and resolved it with updates:

- Make sure that Windows XP is patched up to Service Pack 3 (plus all other downloadable Windows Updates) -- automatic updates don't always download and install all the updates for you, so you'll want to check this web site to be sure you're up-to-date:  http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com/
- Make sure your video card drivers are up-to-date (visit your laptop manufacturer's web site for updates as Windows Updates doesn't always carry the newest video driver updates, especially for laptops):  http://support.lenovo.com/

Answer (score 1):

When you change the screen resolution, do you use the Windows tool (e.g. right-click on the desktop, then in the resulting dialog box, choose Properties...), or do you use the ATI or Intel screen resolution gadget?

We'll probably need to know which T60 you have -- there are (at least) 4 graphic card variants, more if you've actually got a T60p

Have you updated from Lenovo's site?  There are 4 things you might update from this page:
http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-62928.html

Search for "Video" to jump to that section.